# How can my website app publish on facebook timeline when the user is not logged on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token, facebook-timeline

I would like to know if there is a posibility of publishing my actions on facebook timeline if the user is not logged on facebook, I mean through a cron job, actually my users have an extended token, but if they are not connected on facebook, it can't publish anything on their timelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use app access tokens.

> If your app publishes on behalf of its users and requires an access token with no expiration time, you should use an App Access Token. An App Access Token is signed using your app secret and will not expire; it will be invalidated if you re-key/reset your application secret.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a posibility of publishing my actions on facebook timeline if the user is not logged on facebook

Why would you do that, anyway?

Where is the actual *action* the user is undertaking, if they are not even logged in to your site?

Sounds like an *abuse* of Open Graph actions to me.

Comment: yes, they must be logged in my site, but they could not be logged on facebook at the same time

Comment: Well then just see to it, that they are. Aren’t you using a “log in with Facebook” style login system on your site anyways? If not, just implement that - to be able to post actions etc., users log in with Facebook onto your site, and voila, every time you have a fresh and valid access token.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think its possible cause the session does not exits, when you try `$facebook->getAccessToken();` it will return an error if no session exits.